# ggpubr: change font size of stat_compare_means Kruskal-Wallis p-values

Tags: r, ggplot2, kruskal-wallis, ggpubr

How can I change the font size of `stat_compare_means` on the plot below? I.e, change the "Kruskal-Wallis, p = 1.5e-09" and the other p-values font size? I would like to use a smaller font size than the default one...

Following the data example...

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
compare_means(len ~ dose,  data = ToothGrowth)

# Visualize: Specify the comparisons I want
my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )

# Plotting
ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
          color = "dose", palette = "jco")+ 
stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)+ # Add pairwise comparisons p-value
stat_compare_means(label.y = 50)     # Add global p-value
```

Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
your_font_size <- 2

p <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", color = "dose", palette = "jco") + 
 stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons) + 
 stat_compare_means(label.y = 50, size = your_font_size)

p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$textsize <- your_font_size
p
```

[image]

The solution is a bit copious but works. I couldn't find another way to overwrite the `textsize` parameter of the `geom_signif` layer that is created after the first call to `stat_compare_means`.

The parameter is stored here: `p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$textsize` and can manually be modified.

If you need this manipulation for another plot in which the order of the layers might differ from this example, you can use the `which_layer` function from the [`gginnards`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gginnards/) package to detect this layer (or any other) using the following code.

Thanks to [@KGee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7920339/kgee) for pointing out that the `which_layer` function was moved from the [`ggpmisc`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/ggpmisc/) package as of version 0.3.0.

```
library(gginnards)
which_layers(p, "GeomSignif")
## [1] 2
```

Change the `textsize` argument like shown above.

```
p$layers[[which_layers(p, "GeomSignif")]]$aes_params$textsize <- your_font_size
```