# How to add stats for inter and intra comparisons for grouped box plot in ggpubr?

Tags: plot, ggpubr

My aim is to make boxplot with stats between different groups using ggpubr. I use the following code to make the boxplot, but I am not sure how can I include stats for comapirsions between for ex, Control Major against Stress Major or Major against Minor under Control.

```
intensity<-read.table("light_intensity.txt",header = TRUE)
ggboxplot(intensity, x = "Treatment", y = "Intensity",
   color = "Allele", palette = "jco")
```

From this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550525/ggpubr-change-font-size-of-stat-compare-means-kruskal-wallis-p-values), I know that adding

```
stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)
```

could solve my problem. But how to design the **my_comparison** for my specific dataset?

My dataset look like,

```
Allele  Intensity   Treatment
Minor   6723.05258  Control
Minor   7022.128191 Control
Minor   6617.97381  Control
.
.
.
Major   5743.119742 STRESS
Major   5379.326667 STRESS
Major   7256.877569 STRESS
Major   5588.727273 STRESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column to your dataset where `Control Major` as `1`, `Stress Major` as `2`.

Assign the values correspondingly to all your required groups and then create the comparisons of interest.

```
my_comp <- list( c("1", "2"), c("1", "3"), c("2", "3"), c("3", "1"))
```